# QWebView: linkClicked doesn't get emitted with certain page (javascript?)

Tags: qt, webkit, pyqt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I'm trying to open clicked links in a new tab in my application using a QWebView. Even though I bind a slot to the `linkClicked` signal, on a certain page (DuckDuckGo) this signal never gets emitted.

Consider this (PyQt) example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView, QWebPage

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
wv = QWebView()
wv.load(QUrl.fromUserInput(sys.argv[1]))
wv.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
wv.page().linkClicked.connect(lambda url: print("Clicked: " + url.toString()))
wv.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note I set the `linkDelegationPolicy` correctly to `DelegateAllLinks`.

Now when doing something like `python example.py http://www.stackoverflow.com/` and clicking a link, it gets printed to stdout and not opened, like it should.

However when doing the same via `python example.py http://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=foo` and clicking one of the results, the result is simply loaded without me getting a `linkClicked` signal.

My guess would be they somehow dynamically load the opened page via Javascript.

Is there still a way I could force this to be opened in a new tab despite not getting the signal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QWebView Auto Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766186/qwebview-auto-tabs)

Comment: @M4rtini In that question, the asker didn't know about `linkClicked`. My problem is - as shown in my example - `linkClicked` doesn't get emitted when it should. These are two *totally* different things. (Though my last sentence mentions "new tab" because that was my use case for this signal, but I'll clarify this)

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct. You will not get the signal, when web page uses Javascript for navigation.

There is a note about it in [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebpage.html#linkClicked)

**Edit**

I forgot to add that you can try to inject javascript to the page which will use [QT WebKit bridge](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebkit-bridge.html) to communicate with your main application. It may be a good solution, if you want to handle a small set of sites. It will be a difficult task, if you need a general solution working on every possible web page though. There are multiple ways web developers invented for navigation on their pages and you may need a custom javascript for every one of them and a way to find which solution should be applied at any given page.